# $sup \{ \mu (B): B \subset A, B \in K, \mu(B) < \infty \}$ is a measure

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

I'd like to prove that $\mu(A)^* = sup\{\mu (B): B \subset A, B \in K, \mu(B) < \infty \}$ is a measure, where $(X, K, \mu)$ is a measure room and $\mu^*: K \rightarrow [0; \infty]$.

Proof:

It's clear that $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$

Then, I would continue as follows:

> Let $A$ be such that $\mu^*(A) < \infty$ and let $B \subset A$ be a measurable set such that $\mu(B) = \mu^*(A).$ Then $$\mu^*(A \setminus B) = \mu^*(A) - \mu^*(B) = 0.$$

For the previous equalities to be true, we need the assumption $\mu^*(A) < \infty$. This is in general not true otherwise, indeed one can consider $A = \mathbb{R}$ and $B = (0,\infty)$. Then $\mu(A) = \mu(B) = \infty$, but clearly $$\mu(A \setminus B) = \mu((-\infty,0)) = \infty.$$

> This shows that $A \setminus B$ is measurable since by the Caratheodory condition sets of outer measure $0$ are measurable. To conclude the argument it is enough to notice that $A$ belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets since it can be written as the union of two measurable sets: $$A = B \cup (A \setminus B).$$

The result is not true in general if $\mu^*(A) = \infty$. Indeed, let $C \subset (-1,0)$ be a *non*-measurable set and consider $B = (0,\infty)$ and $A = B \cup C$.

Is this a plausible proof?

Comment: The question is not stated clearly. On what sigma algebra do you want the supremum to be a a measure?

Comment: On the Borel sigma algebra.

Comment: To be precise: From the way you formulated your proof, $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $K$ is the Borel sigma algebra? Furthermore $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure? Or is $X$ just some set, $K$ an arbitrary sigma algebra on $X$ and $\mu$ some measure on $K$?

Comment: @humanStampedist Well in the exercise, there it only says that $(X, K, \mu)$ is a measure space. So I assume that $X, K, \mu$ are arbitrary.

Comment: ... but then it doesn't make sense to talk about a Borel $\sigma$-algebra (because in general there is no topology/norm/metric on a measure space). So again: On which sigma algebra do you want $\mu^*$ to be a measure? On $K$?

Comment: Ok, yes, sorry. You're right. In this case, $\mu^*$ should be a measure on $K$.